# Android Studio prevent build API23, I want only API22

Tags: android

How can I stop building for API23? I have many libraries, reduced probably all to API22 from API23. Still I have problems, when want to sync my gradle, it is showing errors in V23 styles.

Is there a way to disable building V23? I don't want to use API23. Don't tell me to update my project to API23 because in my app, permission checking is not necessary. It's inside company app (not for Google Play) and permission dialogs are not necessary.

This is error
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pongodev.layartancepapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.18'
    compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:MaterialPreferenceLibrary:1'
}
```

Comment: What errors exactly are you getting? What are your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Set `targetSdkVersion` to 22.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "building for API23" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare - it's some trash in build generated files from API23 ;/ even target is 22, I bet some library is targeted to API23 but I cannot check every jar and aar

Comment: Did you tried clean+rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You can define compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to 22 in build.gradle
`compileSdkVersion = 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'` 
 buildToolsVersion = "22.0.0"

Comment: But I currently have it, you not understand the question but replying and repeating all known solutions again?
The main problem is that I have 22 set up in gradle. Some library or something is targeted to API23 and it's showing error with not found resources.
I want to force it to not build API23.

Answer (score 0):

These steps works for you:

1.Click build.gradle

2.Change compileSdkVersion 23 to 22

3.Change targetSdkVersion 23 to 22

follow pics
[See Picture for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPDjn.png)